# Why is an exception being called when I set the text of a label to a object in an array?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a label that I want to set its text as an object from and array peopleQuestionArray. I have generated an random int with values ranging from 1-4. My array currently has 4 objects in it. I expect that either the first, second, third, or fourth objects in my array will be displayed, but instead xcode gave me and exception. Does anyone know why. Here's the code I used to set the labels text :

```
int random = (arc4random() % 4) +1;
[quesetionLabel setText:[peopleQuestionArray objectAtIndex:random]];
```

Comment: What's in the `peopleQuestionArray`? Ensure that all objects in it are of type `NSString`.

Comment: btw according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html) you should use `arc4random_uniform(upperBound)` instead of `(arc4random() % 4)` ;)

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: [NSArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html) indexing starts at zero. If you have 4 objects in the array and the value of random is 4, then you'll get an index out of bounds exception (NSRangeException).

Comment: Use *peopleQuestionArray.count* as upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

Your index may go out of range. `NSArray` indices start from 0. So you need to generate a random number ranging from 0-3, not 1-4. Remove the +1 while calculating the random number.

Comment: tried changing it to generate from 0-3 but now the exception is on a different viewcontroller which presents the viewcontroller with the arrays. Heres the code that is causing the exception: questionViewController *qvc = [[questionViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:qvc animated:YES completion:nil];
once again, no specification of the exception by the debugger. It only says (lldb)